# printing from an array struct by reference

Tags: c

I used 6 functions. Three of them (read) are for scanning, and the other ones are for printing (write).I checked the read functions works correctly and the problem is mainly in one of the write functions. The problem is that I scan integers from the user, and store them in a array of structures but when it comes to printing them, I get only the last integers entered.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct
{
    char month[20];
    int day;
    int year;              
} date_t;

typedef struct{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;              
}time_t;

typedef struct
{
    char event[20];
    time_t tm;
    date_t dt;         
}event_t;

int wr_event(const event_t*);
int wr_date(const event_t*);
int wr_time(const event_t*);
int rd_event(event_t*);
int rd_date(event_t*);
int rd_time(event_t*);

int main()
{
    int i,j=0,temp=1;
    event_t ev[5];

    while(temp!=0&&j!=5)
    {
        rd_event(&ev[j]);
        temp=strcmp(ev[j].event,"exit");
        j++;

    }

    if(temp==0)j=j-1;

    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        wr_event(&ev[i]);
    }

}

int rd_time(event_t *ev)
{
    printf("hours->");
    scanf("%d",&ev->tm.hours);       
    printf("minutes->");
    scanf("%d",&ev->tm.minutes);

    printf("secondes->");
    scanf("%d",&ev->tm.seconds);
}

int rd_date(event_t *ev)
{
    printf("day-> ");
    scanf("%d",&ev->dt.day);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("month->");
    gets(ev->dt.month);

    printf("year->");
    scanf("%d",&ev->dt.year);
}

int rd_event(event_t *ev)
{

    printf("\nevent name->");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(ev->event);
    if(strcmp(ev->event,"exit")!=0){

        rd_time(&ev);
        rd_date(&ev);

    }
}

int wr_time(const event_t *ev)
{

    printf("this is the time of the event->%d %d %d\n\n",ev->tm.hours,ev->tm.minutes,ev->tm.seconds);

}

int wr_date(const event_t *ev)
{
    printf("this the date of the event-> %d %s %d\n\n",ev->dt.day,ev->dt.month,ev->dt.year);
}

int wr_event(const event_t *ev)
{
    printf("\nthis is your event-> %s\n\n",ev->event);
    wr_time(&ev);  
    wr_date(&ev);
}
```

Comment: Recommend `scanf("%19s",ev->dt.month)` instead of `gets(ev->dt.month)`.  Same for `event`.

Comment: Question: Who suggested using `fflush(stdin)`?

Comment: @chux The same person who suggested typedeffing a random type to the already-existing standard library typename `time_t` and putting a statically-sized array member into a struct, then `gets()`ing into it without any bounds checking.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - your wr_time/date receive a type event_t*, but you seem to pass them event_t** (taking event_t* and sending it's address with &ev).

Did this code compile for you?

Edit: compiled the code above with gcc, here's the output -

```
  test.c: In function ?rd_event?:
  test.c:78: warning: passing argument 1 of ?rd_time? from incompatible pointer type
  test.c:79: warning: passing argument 1 of ?rd_date? from incompatible pointer type
  test.c: In function ?wr_event?:
  test.c:96: warning: passing argument 1 of ?wr_time? from incompatible pointer type
  test.c:97: warning: passing argument 1 of ?wr_date? from incompatible pointer type
  /tmp/ccwwiaHg.o: In function `rd_date':
  test.c:(.text+0x19d): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

So at least my compiler agrees with me. I'm not familiar with yours, but i'm having a hard time assuming it knows a different language

Comment: yes it does, but it prints the last date and time for all the events.I use C-free v4.0

Comment: @Leeor The argument `&ev[i]` is of the type `event_t*` so it should be fine

Comment: I'm talking about wr_time(&ev); in function wr_event. Come to think of it - in rd_event too.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
notice that pointer is also an address of variable, so you were passed an address of address.. and this was the cause of your problem. also look how scanf function and see how to arange the parentheses

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{ 
  char month[20]; 
  int day; 
  int year;
}date_t;

typedef struct{
  int hours;
  int minutes;
      int seconds;              
}timeT;

typedef struct
{
   char events[20];
   timeT tm;
   date_t dt;         
 }event_t;

 int wr_event(const event_t*);
 int wr_date(const event_t*);
 int wr_time(const event_t*);
 int rd_event(event_t*);
 int rd_date(event_t*);
 int rd_time(event_t*);

 void main()
 {
     int i,j=0,temp=1;
     event_t ev[5];
     char tmp;
     while(temp!=0&&j!=5)
     {
        rd_event(&ev[j]);
        temp=strcmp(ev[j].events,"exit");
        j++;

     }

     if(temp==0)j=j-1;

     for(i=0;i<j;i++){
     wr_event(&ev[i]);

    }
    printf("press any key to exit");
    scanf("%c",&tmp);

}
int rd_time(event_t *ev)
{
     printf("hours->");
     scanf("%d",&(ev->tm.hours));   
     printf("minutes->");
        scanf("%d",&(ev->tm.minutes));

     printf("secondes->");
     scanf("%d",&(ev->tm.seconds));
}
int rd_date(event_t *ev)
{
     printf("day-> ");
        scanf("%d",&(ev->dt.day));
            fflush(stdin);
     printf("month->");
        gets(ev->dt.month);

     printf("year->");
        scanf("%d",&(ev->dt.year));
}
int rd_event(event_t *ev)
{

     printf("\nevent name->");
        fflush(stdin);
     gets(ev->events);
  if(strcmp(ev->events,"exit")!=0){

     rd_time(ev);
     rd_date(ev);

     }
}
int wr_time(const event_t *ev)
{
printf("this is the time of the event->%d %d %d\n\n",ev->tm.hours,ev-  >tm.minutes,ev->tm.seconds);
}
int wr_date(const event_t *ev)
{
printf("this the date of the event-> %d %s %d\n\n",ev->dt.day,ev->dt.month,ev->dt.year);
}

int wr_event(const event_t *ev)
{
    printf("\nthis is your event-> %s\n\n",ev->events);
    wr_time(ev);  
    wr_date(ev); 
}
```

You also need to do checkes, if the user enters digits,numbers or string, otherwise the porgram will go crazy. you also need to check a lot of things, like if the user enters more letters than 20, or something like that. When you create a program that communicate with the user, you have to check for valid input!